# Why does Model::create() make double or nonsequential entries on Chrome but no issue on Edge or some other browsers

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, orm

There seems to be something wrong in laravel ORM functions due to either chrome.

```
Route::get('/admin-panel/zones-add', function () {
    function zoneMake($zone, $company) {
        Zone::create([
            'zone' => $zone,
            'company' => $company,
        ]);
    }
```

If I use the above one, it makes double entries or sometimes non sequential double,single,double entries in the database, in chrome.

If I use it on Edge, it works well.
(Weird that using the Model::create elsewhere and this sometimes doesn't happen but here particularly it does)

```
    function zoneMake($zone, $company) {
        $zoneMaker = new Zone;
        $zoneMaker->zone = $zone;
        $zoneMaker->company = $company;
        $zoneMaker->save();

    }
```

If I use this above one, it makes correct single entries in any browser.

```
    function findCompany($company,$country) {
        return Production::where('country',$country)
        ->first()
        ->shippings
        ->where('company',$company)
        ->first()
        ->id;
    }
    zoneMake('a',findCompany('fedex','us'));
    zoneMake('b',findCompany('fedex','us'));
    zoneMake('c',findCompany('fedex','us'));
    return redirect('/');
});
```

I would appreciate if someone can explain the logic here please (This is obvious but still sharing that I've written both same name functions just for explanation).
(Also, I'm just using routes directly for seeding this specific sort of data)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bring up your browser's developer console, and watch both the Console and Network tabs. Is Chrome making extra requests?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Laravel, there must be a problem on your frontend part

Comment: This probably doesn't have to do with the solution but why do you have a function definition nested inside your `Route::get` closure? It should be just `Route::get('/...', function ($zone, $company){ Zone::create([...]) });`

Comment: @aynber
 So interesting thing... I literally open network&console and it enters it once.... I close it again and it enters it twice... I'm leaning towards the explanation that chrome has a bug